# How to update windows service (Not auto update)

Tags: c#, windows-services

I inherited a couple c# windows service projects. I have fixed some bugs in the code and now I need to deploy the new executable.  What is the normal process for updating / replacing a windows service? I have remote desktop access to the server that I am installing it on.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

For a .Net Windows Service you need to use the InstallUtil command line tool to uninstall the old service, then use it to install the new one.

See...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Not necessary: there is no benefit on unistalling the service if you think to deploy in the same place.

Answer (score 0):

Just **stop** the service and replace the executable and possibli the additional dependency you have updated. Of course it could be helpful have a backup of the running service, just to be safe :)
If you need to know exactly where the service is running, open Service Control Manager, select your serice, and look in the properties/general: you will find the executable path.

Answer (score 0):

It's enough to replace exe and dlls. Obviously you have to stop the service first. If dlls were registered in GAC they might be used by other software on that machine, in such case before compiling and deploying change their version.